# Python ModuleNotFoundError/Importing Issue

Tags: python

My app directory looks like this:

```
app/
    app.py
    config.py
    db.py
    models/
        authentication.py
    resources/
        authentication.py
    routes/
        authentication.py
```

It is a relatively simple flask app, this setup works when hosting the app on heroku however I cannot run it on my local device.

When running as is I receive the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.resources'; 'app' is not a package
```

When renaming app.py to test.py I receive:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

I have played around with an `__init__.py` file and looked at a bunch of similar issues on stack however have not found any fixes that work in my case.

I am using Python 3.9 and the "start/main" file is app.py

Comment: `import app` actually imports `app.py` (instead of the `app` directory), so that's why renaming the file changes the error message. Try to start the application when you are outside the `app` directory.

Comment: What do you mean by ' playing around with an `__init__.py`' exactly? Where did you place it or more specifically them?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I've tried this with no luck, I also tried renaming app.py to test.py as I noticed this before however a new error is raised (output is above)

Comment: @marcelh I've tried placing it with-in the app folder and with-in the directory containing the app folder (singular file)

Comment: please show how you tried to start the app and what exactly does "no luck" mean, that's not an error message I've seen in Python.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko "py app/app.py" with-in the directory containing the app folder, as mentioned previously the error is in the original post. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

Comment: Have you tried to add an `__init__.py` to the folder containing your `app.py` as well as the `resources` folder (possibly the other folders containing `.py` you want to reference as well)?

Comment: yes that's the problem, you have to run it as a module, not as a file: `python -m app.app`

Answer (score 0):

Running the app as a module works

```sh
python -m app.app.py
```